# Getting ORA-01031:insufficient privileges during first time login to oracle 11.2.0.1.0 database on my windows 8 PC

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I installed oracle database 11.2.0.1 on my windows 8.1 PC. I downloaded the zip files from oracle website viz. `win64_11gR2_database_1of2` and `win64_11gR2_database_2of2`.

I followed the installation steps and while attempting to login through sysdba, i got the insufficient privileges issue.
I used below command:

`sqlplus "/as sysdba"`

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are some things which have to be set up correctly:

1. The user you are logged on has to be a member of the **ora_dba** operating system group.
2. The parameter `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(NTS)` must be set correctly. It can include more options but "NTS" is required.
3. You have to connect to the database correctly which is: `sqlplus / as sysdba`. You can also add these quotes but that was Oracle 9i style. But you need a space betweed "/" and "as".

> Note: If you want to connect to Oracle as sysdba from a remote computer, you need a password file.

Comment: Also make sure your user is a member of Windows Group "ORA_DBA"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what ora-600 posted: Did you create and Oracle service? Did you create a database? Can you find the diag directory for the database that you created and drill into the rdbms/SID_NAME/sid_name/trace directory? Installing software does not automatically give you a database. You need to create a database to have a database.